# How to override form action in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, forms, action, drupal-fapi, drupal-alter

I originally started this question in another thread, but that thread was sorta, kinda answered, and now I primarily want to know how to specify another form action... I tried using the code below, but the form action, when output, remains unchanged, although looking at the `print_r($form)`, it's correctly changed...  Why isn't it picking up?

```
function mytheme_user_profile_form($form) {
        global $user;
        $uid = $user->uid;
        //print '<pre>'; print_r($form); print '</pre>';
    $category = $form['_category']['#value'];

    switch($category) {
            case 'account':
                $form['#action'] = '/user/'.$uid.'/edit?destination=user/'.$uid;
                        break;
        case 'education':
                        $form['#action'] = '/user/'.$uid.'/edit/education?destination=user/'.$uid;
                        break;
        case 'experience':
                        $form['#action'] = '/user/'.$uid.'/edit/experience?destination=user/'.$uid;
                        break;
            case 'publications':
                        $form['#action'] = '/user/'.$uid.'/edit/publications?destination=user/'.$uid;
                        break;
        case 'conflicts':
                        $form['#action'] = '/user/'.$uid.'/edit/conflicts?destination=user/'.$uid;
                        break;
    }

        //print '<pre>'; print_r($form); print '</pre>';
        //print $form['#action'];
        $output .= drupal_render($form);
        return $output;
```

Comment: sorta / kinda? ;)  def. let me know if you need more help.

Comment: If you want to edit the action url, I found this article which helped me: http://actionscript-flash-guru.com/blog/47-exposed-form-in-block-change-the-action-url--drupal-6--views--hookformalter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter/6) is likely the way to go.
Here are some hopefully helpful links:

[Form Theming: How do I set $form['action']?](http://drupal.org/node/304170)

[Modifying Forms in Drupal 5 and 6](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/modifying-forms-5-and-6)

[hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter/6)

EDIT: reply to comment #1 below:

**How to implement hook_form_alter()**:

You must create a module (you cannot use `template.php`).  It's easier than it looks.

For a module named "formstuff", you would create `formstuff.info` and `formstuff.module` and put them in either `sites/all/modules` or `sites/yoursitename/modules`.  Set up the .info and .module files per [the instructions](http://drupal.org/node/206753), then just create the following function in your .module file:

```
function formstuff_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  // do stuff
}
```

This function is a hook because it is named properly (i.e. replace the word 'hook' with the name of your module), and it matches `hook_form_alter`'s function signature (i.e. it takes the same parameters).

Then just enable your module in your site's admin and the hook should do it's magic.

Note that `hook_form_alter` takes a reference to the form; this allows you to modify it in-place.

Comment: I tried using form_alter, but it didn't work.  Although, I put the code in my template.php file.  Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `form_alter` function in a module and then use either `if` or `switch` to check the form ID. If the form ID is the one you want to alter then give the form an action property

```
$form['someID'] = array(
'#action' => 'path/you/want',
);
```

Comment: I tried this, added it to my my.module and flushed the caches,etc., but still didn't work: 

<pre>
function user_profile_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
 switch($form_id) {
  case 'user_profile_form':
  if(arg(0) == 'user' && is_int(arg(1))) {
   if($form['_category']['#value'] == 'education') {
    $form['#action'] = 'user/'.arg(1).'/edit/education';
   }
  }
                break;
 }
}
</pre>

Comment: The function name should be "my_module_form_alter". To avoid the switch statement, you can use "my_module_form_user_profile_form_alter", assuming you have the form id right.